# TCL. How to check if procedure exists?

Tags: tcl

I need to check if procedure `func1` exists and result (if exists `1` if not `0`) put in `variable proc_ststus_var` . How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`info procs  ?pattern?` will give you the basic building block for what you want:

```
% proc foo {} {}
% info procs foo
foo
% info procs bar
%
```

Something like:

```
% proc procExists p {
   return uplevel 1 [expr {[llength [info procs $p]] > 0}]
}
% procExists foo
1
% procExists bar
0
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know to do it :)

Comment: Note that the above works with a pattern, that is, `procExists fo*` will return true. If you don't want that behavior, look for the exact name in the list returned by `info procs` directly.

Comment: Be aware that running `info procs` in a procedure may change the context namespace; library-quality code will use; `uplevel 1 [list info procs $p]` instead.

Comment: Added `uplevel 1` following @Donal Fellows' comment.

Answer (score 8):

Note that if you check if a procedure with certain meta characters (`*`, `?`) exists, `info commands` might return the wrong result.

So to check if a procedure exists, use either `namespace which` or check the result of `info commands`:

```
if {[llength [namespace which $cmdname]]} {
    ...
}
if {$cmdname in [info commands $cmdname]} {
    ...
}
```

Tcl's `unknown` uses the `namespace which` approach.

Answer (score 4):

you can try something like

```
set commandExists [ info commands "mycommandname" ];
```

Comment: `info commands` checks for commands, not procedures (which are subclass of command, really). It also returns a list of command names, not a boolean…